# My OpenCL code is slower on GPU than on my CPU

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I am starting with OpenCL for some computer vision tasks. I use the python `pyopencl` module. My code runs faster on an Intel cpu than on my Nvidia GTX 750Ti.

I have an example code that multiplies a (2000x4000) Array item-wise. It runs in `2ms` on my cpu and in `8ms` on my gpu. As you can see in the code, the time spent is just the kernel call.

Why is it so much slower on my GPU?

```py
import time
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl

devices = cl.get_platforms()[1].get_devices()

ctx = cl.Context(devices)
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

kernel = cl.Program(
    ctx, """
        kernel void mult(
            global float *a,
            global float *b,
            global float *out
        )
        {
            int row = get_global_id(0);
            int col = get_global_id(1);

            int cols = get_global_size(1);

            int index = col + row * cols;
            out[index] = a[index] * b[index];
        }
    """).build()

a = np.random.rand(2000, 4000).astype(np.float32)
a_b = cl.Buffer(ctx, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=a.flatten())

rows, cols = a.shape

out_b = cl.Buffer(ctx, cl.mem_flags.WRITE_ONLY, size=rows*cols*np.dtype(np.float32).itemsize)

start = time.time() * 1000
kernel.mult(queue, a.shape, None, a_b, a_b, out_b)
end = time.time() * 1000

print(f"{end-start}ms")

out = np.empty(a.shape, dtype=np.float32)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, out, out_b)

# make sure result is correct
np.testing.assert_array_equal(a*a, out)
```

Here is the output of `clinfo`

```
> clinfo
Number of platforms                               2
  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
  Platform Vendor                                 NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 9.1.84
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer
  Platform Extensions function suffix             NV

  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) CPU Runtime for OpenCL(TM) Applications
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel(R) Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.1 LINUX
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_spir cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_intel_vec_len_hint
  Platform Host timer resolution                  1ns
  Platform Extensions function suffix             INTEL

  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     GeForce GTX 750 Ti
  Device Vendor                                   NVIDIA Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x10de
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
  Driver Version                                  390.116
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Topology (NV)                            PCI-E, 01:00.0
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Max compute units                               5
  Max clock frequency                             1084MHz
  Compute Capability (NV)                         5.0
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     1
    Supported partition types                     None
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             1024x1024x64
  Max work group size                             1024
  Preferred work group size multiple              32
  Warp size (NV)                                  32
  Preferred / native vector sizes
    char                                                 1 / 1
    short                                                1 / 1
    int                                                  1 / 1
    long                                                 1 / 1
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 1
    double                                               1 / 1        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  Yes
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              2096300032 (1.952GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           524075008 (499.8MiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              No
  Integrated memory (NV)                          No
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       4096 bits (512 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        81920 (80KiB)
  Global Memory cache line size                   128 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             32
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            134217728 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Max 2D image size                             16384x16384 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             4096x4096x4096 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 256
    Max number of write image args                16
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               49152 (48KiB)
  Registers per block (NV)                        65536
  Max number of constant args                     9
  Max constant buffer size                        65536 (64KiB)
  Max size of kernel argument                     4352 (4.25KiB)
  Queue properties
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Prefer user sync for interop                    No
  Profiling timer resolution                      1000ns
  Execution capabilities
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No
    Kernel execution timeout (NV)                 Yes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution (NV)       Yes
    Number of async copy engines                  1
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer

  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) CPU Runtime for OpenCL(TM) Applications
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
  Device Vendor                                   Intel(R) Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 2.1 (Build 0)
  Driver Version                                  18.1.0.0920
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 2.0
  Device Type                                     CPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Max compute units                               4
  Max clock frequency                             3100MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     4
    Supported partition types                     by counts, equally, by names (Intel)
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             8192x8192x8192
  Max work group size                             8192
  Preferred work group size multiple              128
  Max sub-groups per work group                   1
  Preferred / native vector sizes
    char                                                 1 / 16
    short                                                1 / 8
    int                                                  1 / 4
    long                                                 1 / 2
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 8
    double                                               1 / 4        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              8308092928 (7.738GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           2077023232 (1.934GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Shared Virtual Memory (SVM) capabilities        (core)
    Coarse-grained buffer sharing                 Yes
    Fine-grained buffer sharing                   Yes
    Fine-grained system sharing                   Yes
    Atomics                                       Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Preferred alignment for atomics
    SVM                                           64 bytes
    Global                                        64 bytes
    Local                                         0 bytes
  Max size for global variable                    65536 (64KiB)
  Preferred total size of global vars             65536 (64KiB)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        262144 (256KiB)
  Global Memory cache line size                   64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             480
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            129813952 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Base address alignment for 2D image buffers   64 bytes
    Pitch alignment for 2D image buffers          64 pixels
    Max 2D image size                             16384x16384 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 480
    Max number of write image args                480
    Max number of read/write image args           480
  Max number of pipe args                         16
  Max active pipe reservations                    65535
  Max pipe packet size                            1024
  Local memory type                               Global
  Local memory size                               32768 (32KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     480
  Max constant buffer size                        131072 (128KiB)
  Max size of kernel argument                     3840 (3.75KiB)
  Queue properties (on host)
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
    Local thread execution (Intel)                Yes
  Queue properties (on device)
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
    Preferred size                                4294967295 (4GiB)
    Max size                                      4294967295 (4GiB)
  Max queues on device                            4294967295
  Max events on device                            4294967295
  Prefer user sync for interop                    No
  Profiling timer resolution                      1ns
  Execution capabilities
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
    Sub-group independent forward progress        No
    IL version                                    SPIR-V_1.0
    SPIR versions                                 1.2
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_spir cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_intel_vec_len_hint

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  No platform
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              Success [NV]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No platform
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about pyOpenCL, but I do know OpenCL a bit...

The GTX 750 TI has 5 compute units and 640 CUDA cores, meaning your optimal local work size is `640/5 = 128`. Using smaller/larger values will only waste resources. I don't know what the library does when you pass `None', but this is one key aspect to get performance. I strongly suggest you look at what values are used.

Generally speaking, reading and writing back to global memory directly is 'slow'. Each compute unit has a certain amount of local memory that can (and should) be leveraged. I'm not sure this is suitable for a kernel as simple as yours, but I'd try storing the results in local memory before transferring back to main memory. You can cast to larger data types to improve throughput between local and global memory too.

Finally, it wouldn't be surprising that transferring data from/to GPU takes more time than doing the actual computation.

Answer (score 0):

Memory transfers from CPU to GPU and back via PCIe usually have a latency in the order of 10µs, independent on how much data you transfer. This means that large data transfers are more efficient and for small data sets the latency might be longer than the execution time on a CPU.

Your matrix multiplication kernel can be optimized to run approximately 10x faster. The key word here is cache tiling with local memory. The idea is to load chunks of data from global memory to local memory in a single coalesced transfer and then access one element at a time from local memory. This reduces global memory access latency a lot and will substantially speed up the kernel.